# PhpStorm exclude excel temporary files from upload

Tags: pattern-matching, phpstorm

I want to exclude files like this from upload: `~$test.xlsx`

I'm using tools/deployment/options. I tried:

> ~$*

but didn't work. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you cannot use `$` there (it may have special meaning in the underlying pattern matching engine).

This pattern works just fine:

> ~*

It should be OK to use it for your case.. as normally you do not name real project files with leading `~` character... But if anything, you could be more specific and try `~*.xlsx` instead.